# Transfer data from server to server SAS without SAS/CONNECT license

Tags: sas

We need to transfer a file (.sashdata) from server to another. The limit is to not use SAS/CONNECT.

1. Is it possibile to perform this task with SAS code?
2. Is it possibile to perform this task with FTP/SFTP?

Comment: 1. SO is for programming questions 2. One question at the time. Please read [ask]

Comment: Since it's .sashdat, can that server start a CAS connection and download it from there? Otherwise you'll need to save it to a CASLIB and SFTP it over. SFTP is typically the easiest method for transferring sashdat or sas7bdat files. Just be mindful of the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Server to Server transfer can be performed, but that requires host side actions.  SAS Servers by default have option `NOXCMD` active which mean SAS code run on the server cannot perform host side actions.

You should coordinate with your SAS admins to effectuate a server-to-server transfer (i.e. host side scp or winscp)

The alternative is to have a client machine that receives a download from host A and then uploads to host B.  The client would need access to both hosts and the security rights to download and upload the data set in question.  The client machine app can be Enterprise Guide.